# Finding what is the same with two arrays with duplicates

Tags: ruby

I want to find all elements that are the same between two arrays, including elements that are repeated multiple times in both arrays. For instance, I want

```
[1,1,1,2]
```

and

```
[1,1,3,4]
```

to give

```
[1,1]
```

I could iterate through the array and keep track of it, but I was wondering if there were a more ruby way of doing this.

Comment: What would you expect `[1,2]` and `[1,1,3]` to return? `[1]` or `[1,1]`?

Comment: @spickermann `[1]`

Comment: @Blubber: Are you looking for the longest shared sequence in two arrays or all the elements they share with duplication?

Comment: @Linuxios all the elements they share, even if it isn't duplicated

Comment: Ordered or unordered? What would happen with `[1,1,6,11]` and `[42,1,23,11,1]`? You'd expect `[1,1,11]`, `[1,11,1]`, or `[11,1,1]` right?

Comment: @muistooshort doesn't matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want [multiset-intersection](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Multiplicity_function). There is no multiset datastructure in the Ruby core lib or stdlib, but there are multiple implementations you can find on the web. I'll just [randomly pick one](http://maraigue.hhiro.net/multiset/) (it doesn't really matter, multiset is a mathematical concept with strict definition, all implementations behave more or less the same):

```
require 'multiset'

ms = Multiset[1, 1, 1, 2] & Multiset[1, 1, 3, 4]
#=> #<Multiset:#2 1>

ms.to_a
#=> [1, 1]
```

If you must, you can convert it to an array using [`Multiset#to_a`](http://maraigue.hhiro.net/multiset/doc5/Multiset.html#method-i-to_a), but remember: most of the interesting methods you can call on [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) are actually from the [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) mixin and thus available to all collections; you often don't actually need to have an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,1,1,2,5]
b = [1,1,3,2,4,2]

def counting_hash(arr)
   arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
end

hb = counting_hash(b)
  #=> {1=>2, 3=>1, 2=>2, 4=>1}
counting_hash(a).each_with_object([]) do |(k,v),a|
  n = [v, hb[k]].min
  n.times { a << k } if n > 0
end
  #=> [1, 1, 2]
```

Note that

```
counting_hash(a)
  #=> {1=>3, 2=>1, 5=>1}
```

and

```
hb[5]
  #=> 0
```

as `hb` has a default value of zero.